# Linux server ssh keeps asking for password, what is the correct setup, what is missing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to connect to ssh2 server. I am able to connect via password, but I needed to setup ssh, so i created the `ssh-keygen` locally and copied it to server using command `ssh-copy-id root@IP_ADDRESS`, and double checked, its saved in folder `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

I changed `home` and `.ssh` and `authorized key permissions` but nothing seems to help and server keeps asking for password.

```
chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Also I have looked in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to make sure everything is ok. Following are configurations

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I also restarted ssh-service everytime I made some change `sudo systemctl restart ssh.service`. This is getting really frustrating now. A simple setup is not working and taking me hours.

Root folder permissions

```
drwx------  12 root root    20480 Apr  7 00:52 root
```

.ssh folder permissions

```
drwx------   2 root root  4096 Apr  7 00:32 .ssh
```

authorized_keys permissions

```
-rw------- 1 root root 563 Apr  7 00:07 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

**Log using ssh -vv**

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ad/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname **********:2e0c::2 is address
debug1: Connecting to **********:2e0c::2 [**********:2e0c::2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ad/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u7
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to **********::2:22 as 'user'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/ad/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:**********/***joHf2Me+/8X6H3WnPXZLQR1fE1s6Q
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/ad/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '**********::2' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ad/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:*********/7Dd/3o******DYua3nreWs
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:*********/7Dd/3o******DYua3nreWs
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ad/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: What is the ssh versions on the two sides?

Comment: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u7, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017 on server and locally OpenSSH_8.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021.

Comment: Edited my comment, listed both versions. The server is using an old version. Since it's a client's server. Is it safe to upgrade? Could this be the cause of error?

Comment: It's new enough that it should support RSA, but you should upgrade anyway. Openssl 1.0 is *ancient*. In addition, best practice is to never use the root user, but rather rely on sudo or escalating privileges after logging in.

Comment: sure I will do that. Is there anything else you think is not setup correctly for ssh ?

Comment: upgrade first then consider again to ask. what that box, debian 3?